# scala 2.10.2 calling a 'macro method' with generic type not work

Tags: scala, generics, scala-macros

I define following macro to transform case fields to map

```
   import scala.language.experimental.macros
    import scala.reflect.macros.Context

    def asMap_impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(t: c.Expr[T]) = {
      import c.universe._

      val mapApply = Select(reify(Map).tree, newTermName("apply"))

      val pairs = weakTypeOf[T].declarations.collect {
        case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor =>
          val name = c.literal(m.name.decoded)
          val value = c.Expr(Select(t.tree, m.name))
          reify(name.splice -> value.splice).tree
      }

      c.Expr[Map[String, Any]](Apply(mapApply, pairs.toList))
    }
```

And the method implementation

```
def asMap[T](t: T) = macro asMap_impl[T]
```

Then I define a case class to test it

```
case class User(name : String)
```

It works fine(with scala repl):

```
 scala> asMap(User("foo")) res0:
 scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(name -> foo)
```

**But When I wrap this method with another generic method**

```
def printlnMap[T](t: T) = println(asMap(t))
```

This method always print empty map:

```
scala> printlnMap(User("foo"))
Map()
```

The type information seems lost, how to get the printlnMap to print all fields ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is that your macro will be called only once - when compiling `printlnMap` function. This way it will see `T` as an abstract type. The macro will not be called on each invocation of `printlnMap`.

One way to quickly fix this is to implement `printlnMap` also as a macro. Of course, this is not ideal. So, here's a different approach - materialization of typeclass instances:

First, define a typeclass that will allow us to convert case class instances to maps:

```
trait CaseClassToMap[T] {
  def asMap(t: T): Map[String,Any]
}
```

Then, implement a macro that will *materialize* an instance of this type class for some case class `T`. You can put it into `CaseClassToMap` companion object so that it is visible globally.

```
object CaseClassToMap {
  implicit def materializeCaseClassToMap[T]: CaseClassToMap[T] = macro impl[T]

  def impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[CaseClassToMap[T]] = {
    import c.universe._

    val mapApply = Select(reify(Map).tree, newTermName("apply"))

    val pairs = weakTypeOf[T].declarations.collect {
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor =>
        val name = c.literal(m.name.decoded)
        val value = c.Expr(Select(Ident(newTermName("t")), m.name))
        reify(name.splice -> value.splice).tree
      }

    val mapExpr = c.Expr[Map[String, Any]](Apply(mapApply, pairs.toList))

    reify {
      new CaseClassToMap[T] {
        def asMap(t: T) = mapExpr.splice
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you can do this:

```
def asMap[T: CaseClassToMap](t: T) =
  implicitly[CaseClassToMap[T]].asMap(t)

def printlnMap[T: CaseClassToMap](t: T) =
  println(asMap(t))
```

Comment: How about higher kind type? Eg. printMap[B, A[B]](a : A[B]) = println(asMap(a)) , it doesn't compile

Comment: Can you help me with higher kinded type

Comment: @jilen There's no higher kinded type used in your example. The method should work fine for case classes with type parameters, if this is what you meant.

Comment: I want to define a function def call[R,A[R] <:Req[R]: CaseClassToMap](req:A[R]) :R= doSomething(asMap(req)),the compiler complains A takes type parameter

Comment: @jilen Didn't you mean `def call[R,A <: Req[R]: CaseClassToMap](req: A): R` ? I don't see a reason to use higher kinds there.

Comment: define call that way the R is always inefered to `Nothing`

Comment: @jilen Hard to say anything without full example. I think you should ask a separate question about this.