# In scala macro, how to retrieve full type information from a WeakTypeTag?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-2.13

I'm writing macro to convert a type description into a singleton type:

```
object Type2String {

  def apply[I]: Witness.Lt[String] = macro Macros.apply[I]

  final class Macros(val c: whitebox.Context) extends MWithReflection {

    import c.universe._

    def apply[A: WeakTypeTag]: Tree = {

      val tt: Type = weakTypeOf[A]
      val str = tt.toString

      // val vv = viz(tt)

      q"shapeless.Witness.mkWitness[$str]($str)"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that since A only has a WeakTypeTag. It cannot extract the correct info from generic types:

```
  case class ^^[T1, T2]() {

    final val wTSelf = Type2String[^^[T1, T2]]
  }


    val e1 = ^^[Int, String]()

    e1.wTSelf
```

This gives the wrong Witness type: `shapeless.Witness.Aux[String("T1 ^^ T2")]`

So my questions are:

1. It is compile-time, the type information should be fully visible, why are T1 and T2 erased?
2. How to fix this program so it gives the correct type info:

`shapeless.Witness.Aux[String("Int ^^ String")]`

?

Comment: The macro inlines the result just once, when the class is defined. The common pattern to circumvent this is to accept an implicit that will be regenerated on every construction of `^^`, and that would still not save you in case it's being constructed inside a generic method. You might want to look into using a regular `TypeTag` instead of a weak one to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @OlegPyzhcov, unfortunately I don't think it is possible to use TypeTag directly in macro. Using it indirectly means introducing extra runtime overhead and a chain of context bound, which is weird considering that this macro happens strictly at compile-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, @oleg-pyzhcov pointed out very clearly the problem: your macro is expanded when you define the class, and here the compiler *can't* know what actual type is used.

For the second question, @oleg-pyzhcov is right again. Indeed there is a similar example that uses implicit to solve your problem ([scala 2.10.2 calling a 'macro method' with generic type not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763434/scala-2-10-2-calling-a-macro-method-with-generic-type-not-work)).

So I have tried to change your code a little in order to successufly return the right type:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox
import scala.language.experimental.macros
trait Type2String[T] {
  def apply() : Witness.Lt[String]
}

object Type2String {
  implicit def materializeType2String[T]: Type2String[T] = macro impl[T]

  def impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Expr[Type2String[T]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val tt: Type = weakTypeOf[T]
    val str = tt.toString
    //val vv = viz(tt) I don't know what is viz(tt)...

    reify {
      () => c.Expr[Witness.Lt[String]](q"shapeless.Witness.mkWitness[$str]($str)").splice
    }
  }
}
```

and then you have to should write a little more code in the class definition:

```
case class ^^[T1, T2]()(implicit val type2String: Type2String[^^[T1, T2]]) {
  final val wTSelf = type2String()
}
//or
case class ^^^[T1, T2]() {
  final def wTSelf(implicit type2String: Type2String[^^[T1, T2]]) = type2String()
}

val e1 = ^^[Int, String]()
//val e2 = ^^^[String, Double]()
e1.wTSelf
```

And that is.

Comment: @tribbloid it is what are you looking for or I've missed some relevant details?

Comment: It is a good idea, but just like the method to declare an `implicit val ttg: TypeTag[^^[T1, T2]]`, it still demands a chain of context bound.

Comment: Accepted anyway as it may be a compiler limitation